# Discord bot "The application did not respond" yet the command send?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

Im working on my discord bot, And upon sending a slash command, the bot always seems to send a "The application did not respond" message even if the command works.

No errors show up in my log, Curious if anyone has a similar experience?

```
#Verify command
@bot.slash_command()
async def verify(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Welcome to the Galaxy!", delete_after=10)
    member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=891110682110623806 )
    unverified = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=1012034653613477961)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(member)
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(unverified)
```

This is the code the message shows up on. Using /verify it gives the user roles, Takes away the other role correctly. Then still sends the message "The application did not respond" right after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always send a response when using Slash Commands to prevent this error message to show up:

```py
#Verify command
@bot.slash_command()
async def verify(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f"Welcome to the Galaxy!", delete_after=10)
    member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=891110682110623806 )
    unverified = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, id=1012034653613477961)
    await ctx.author.add_roles(member)
    await ctx.author.remove_roles(unverified)
    ctx.send("Roles added successfully")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `ctx.respond` instead of `ctx.send`

Comment: can you describe why this solution works? Please ad a bit more detail to this answer.