# Why does my discord bot say it did not respond after it did?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I've been testing out the basics of writing a discord bot for a little project I'm working on, and I noticed that while the bot responds as intended when given a slash command, the sent command its self says that the application failed to respond. If anyone can point out where I'm being stupid, that would be much appreciated!

Here are some images of the problem

I send the command...
[image]
it works...
but the application didn't respond apparently?
[image]

Here's the test slash command that I'm using

```
@tree.command(name = "test", description = "test", guild=discord.Object(id=(idnu))
async def lal(ctx, last: str):
        response = "strresponse"
        await ctx.channel.send(response)
```

I also looked at a couple posts which are similar, I.E
[Discord bot "The application did not respond" yet the command send?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74758439/discord-bot-the-application-did-not-respond-yet-the-command-send)
but none seemed to answer my question, as I'm already responding last?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `discord.app_commands`, not `discord.ext.commands`.

When definig a command using `app_commands`, the first command parameter is not from type `commands.Context`, its [`discord.Interaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands#interaction).

Both objects (`ctx` and `interaction`) has a channel object as property so the message is being sent. However, this is **not the way you are suppose to handle an interaction**.

All `app_commands` must have a response, that can be sent using the [`response`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands#discord.Interaction.response) object property from the `interaction` object.

This is how your command should look like:

```
from discord import app_commands, Interaction

@bot.tree.command(name='test', description='command description')
@app_commands.describe(last = '"last" parameter description') # Optional line
async def test(interaction : Interaction, last : str):
    response = "str_response"
    await interaction.response.send_message(response)
```

My previous sentence:

> "All app_commands must have a response, that can be sent using the response attribute from the interaction object"

doesn't mean that you can't send "standard message" (`channel.send()`) as part of the command, but that you have to response to the **interaction** at least once.

Interaction responses are the type of messages that look like this:

[image: Interaction response example]

If you want your command to only include "standard messages", you can set to `True` the `ephemeral` parameter when responding to the interaction with the [`send_message()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands#discord.InteractionResponse.send_message) coroutine from the response object.

Making the response `ephemeral` makes the interaction response only visible for the user that executed the command, and it can be deleted at any time clicking on "Delete this message" (or "Eliminar este mensaje" in the next picture, sorry, I have Discord in Spanish):

```
@bot.tree.command(name='test', description='command description')
@app_commands.describe(last = '"last" parameter description')
async def test(interaction : Interaction, last : str):
    response = "str_response"
    await interaction.channel.send(response)
    await interaction.response.send_message(content='Message Sent!', ephemeral=True)
```

[image: Second example]

Finally, if you want your command to include more than one interaction response, or you are expecting the command execution to not be brief (slow code, etc.) you have to [`defer`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands#discord.InteractionResponse.defer) the response, and then send the responses using [`interaction.followup.send()`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands#discord.Interaction.followup) instead of `interaction.response.send_message()`:

```
@bot.tree.command(name='test', description='command description')
@app_commands.describe(last = '"last" parameter description')
async def test(interaction : Interaction, last : str):
    await interaction.response.defer()
    await interaction.followup.send('str_response')
    await interaction.followup.send('Another response!')
```

[image: Third example]

Now you are ready to join the `app_commands` commands side!

Comment: I just realized that in the command decorator I didn't add the `guild=discord.Object(id=(idnu))` part. You don't have to remove it, I just forgot to add it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it like this:

```py
@tree.command(name = "test", description = "test", guild=discord.Object(id=(idnu))
async def lal(interaction: discord.Interaction):
        response = "strresponse"
        await interaction.response.send_message(response)
```